# Is there an Azure API for javascript to get resource owner's email and name?

Tags: node.js, azure

I know the resource and resource group name, I am using NodeJS to acess Azure Node SDK/API. Could someone let me know if there are any api's that I can access to get the resource owner's name and email using the information that I have?

I have tried azure-arm-resource manager, but it return's just the admin name. I need the email too.

Comment: What is the owner of a resource you said? Does it mean creator for the resource?

Comment: Yeah, creator of the resource. Be it a VM or Storage, I will just have the information about resource name and the resource group name. I want the email and name of the resource creator

Answer (score 0):

Use microsoft graph API 
reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#GetAUser

Comment: Yeah, I was looking into it,  I don't have the user id information. So I don't think I can use that API I will have resource name and resource group name and bunch of other details about the resource